# How to solve my error LNK2019

Tags: java, c++

I have met with LNK2019 error. The details are

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol **imp__JAWT_GetAWT@8
>   referenced in function "struct HWND** * **cdecl
>   getHwndFromComponent(class *jobject *,struct JNIEnv* *)"
>   (?getHwndFromComponent@@YAPAUHWND**@@PAV_jobject@@PAUJNIEnv_@@@Z)

What I am building is a **Win32 Console Application** in DLL type.

I have included `jawt_md.h`. At first, I think it is the problem of 64 bit Java, so I have done things below:

1, Install a 32 bit java

2, Add C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\include\win32; to Additional Include Directories.

3, Make sure the java be called in OS level is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin. (Use `java -version` to test it)

However, I still meet the same issue when building the project.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: There will be a .lib file or a .dll providing the functions defined in `jawt_md.h`. You will have to specify the .lib library file and its path to the linker or add code to load the DLL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: undefined reference/unresolved external symbol is singlehandedly the worst error you can ever achieve -> A linkage error. C++ Doesn't even give you a detailed reason as to why. Usually it has to do with the following things: You haven't included the file in your includes, or your computer is missing a library you are trying to use.

Comment: @user4581301. Thanks. It helps.

Comment: @NoamRodrik Thanks for your detailed explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAWT is a shared library, which means you need to link with it.

Try this:

1. add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\lib` as an additional library path (under linker settings)
2. add `jawt` as an additional library (under linker settings)